# PostgreSql Equivalent of sqlplus -S username/password \@lock?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, sqlplus, psql

What will be Postgres equivalent of following:

```
sqlplus -S username/password \@lock.
```

Also what does @lock means here?

Comment: You need to explain what the `sqlplus` command line is doing. You can't expect that people that know Postgres know all `sqlplus` parameters as well.

Comment: It means "after logging in, execute the script lock.sql". The `\\` is probably not necessary but is there to ensure the sqlplus command sees the `@` rather than being interpreted by the shell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PostgreSQL, but - as of Oracle, here you are:

That command means that

- you'll connect to Oracle's command line tool called SQL*Plus (executable name is `sqlplus`)
- in silent mode (that's what `-s` does)
- providing username and password
- and execute .SQL script whose name is `lock` (I have no idea what it does; you'll have to open it in any text editor and have a look)

---

Now, how someone establishes connection to PostgreSQL and runs a .SQL script, that's something I wouldn't know, but - reading online documentation - it might be

```
psql -U username -d database_name -a -f lock
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the explanations in the comments and the other answer, the equivalent in PostgreSQL should be

```sh
psql 'user=username password=password dbname=mydatabase' -f lock
```